How to pass the value of a variable to a handlebars block
I am working on some HTML code that uses handlebars templates for storing some internal variables. I am not very familiar with handlebars so forgive me if my phrasing is a little off. Basically, my issue is that I have a long list of variables that I want to access through handlebars. I want to do this by referencing an array of strings that I have that names all of the variables.
I could hard code this by just putting each in individually as such:
A = {{variable0}}; B = {{variable1}}
and so on for variable0 to variablen. What I want to do is make a loop that would accomplish this for me. something like:
for (var i = 0; i <  n; i++) {
   result[i] = 'variable' + i
}
A = {{result[0]}};
B = {{result[1]}};

I was hoping that {{result[0]}} would behave equivalently to {{variable0}} but it does not. Is there a way to use a string stored in a variable that would accomplish this?

It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Could you look at this link and tell me if it's on the right track?: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/Lxnstkbd/

You can access global variables as keys to the global object window. Ideally though, you should use another object and not the window.
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  result[i] = window['variable' + i]
}

A = {{ result[0] }};
B = {{ result[1] }};

